# How to run a script on a database in command line (MySQL Server)

Tags: mysql, command-line

I have just installed MySQL Community Server and now want to create a database and then run a script on it in a command line.

I tried this one but looks like it doesn't work:

```
CREATE DATABASE admin_web_projektu
mysql admin_web_projektu < c:/USI-4/db_template_001.sql
```

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: make sure you have logged in to mysql on command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below steps:

1. `Create database` yourdbname;
2. `use` yourdbname;
3. `source` path_to_DB_script;

Comment: I tried what you suggested and here is the result:
                                                                                                                                                                           ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'src c
:/USI-4/db_template_001.sql' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE YourTable
```

References: read this for more detail http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the MySQL console to run your command.

```
mysql> exit
$ mysql -uroot -ppassword -B database < /path/to/script.sql
```

The `-u` indicates user, `-p` operator indicates the password and `-B` the database to use. Note that there is no gap between the `-p` and the password, otherwise MySQL considers the space part of the password. I tend to leave out a space before the username too :) old habits I guess.

The greater and less than operators `<` and `>` act as directional indicators for your bash commands. Think of them as 'into'. So the above statement might be stated as follows:

```
$ database (into) file
```

If you were dumping the database into a file, your direction would be `>` toward the file. However, you want to put the file 'into' the database, so the direction is `<`. Maybe that helps?